# can we use firebase as remote source with room as a single source of truth in paging library?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, paging

I want to use the paging library in my project where my remote data source is Firebase Firestore and my local data source or single source of truth is a room database, but when I searched, I did not get any tutorial or GitHub sample code to implement these all together.

And one problem I am facing in paging Library is that when I am using these all together then the first time it loads the items, but when I scroll the list it did not call the load function again to append more data, but when I close the app and again open, then it loads more data.

I tried a lot to implement it, but did not get success, do you have any resources to implement these. any GitHub resource?

I found many examples and resources that use remote data sources using a retrofit, but not with Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

> I did not get any tutorial or GitHub sample code to implement these all together.

That's most likely because Firestore already has its own persistence mechanism. For Android and iOS, [it is enabled by default](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence). So there is no need to create an additional local database because Firestore maintains a local copy of the database. This is needed for offline usage.

When it comes to pagination, I think that the following resource will help:

- [How to implement pagination in Firestore using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5)

Comment: Hey Subham. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: yes bro, you are right, that is why I did not get any such example that uses them all together

Comment: So do you need some additional information?

Comment: No, as you described that Firestore already has its own persistence mechanism so now I will not use an additional local database.